# 'Unknown users' in Windows 8 challenge page

Tags: bug, status-completed, windows-8-challenge

[image]

Apparently two of the folk involved in the Windows 8 challenge seem to be referred to as 'unknown user'. Clicking on them seems to indicate they're both users in good standing. Looks like a bug to me.

Comment: For me last two unknowns are windows8fanatic and r.tanner.f respectively. So I think its generating randomly for different user's.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is fixed now. We forgot to remove some hard-coded values specific to Ask Different's [Mountain Lion Challenge promo](http://mountainlionchallenge.com/), which was preventing more than 20 users from being loaded.